# vue 3 script setup bind v-model to child custom component multiple checkbox

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have looked at many examples of how to do two-way binding of model data, but examples with text inputs are reported everywhere. I work according to the same scheme and get errors.

```js
const models = ref({
    teams: {
        items: usePage().props.value.teams,
        selected: [],
        isCheckAll: false,
    },
    
});
```

```html
<template>
    
        <LineTeamsIndex
            v-model:selected-items="models.teams.selected"
            v-model:isCheckAll="models.teams.isCheckAll"
            :teams="$page.props.teams"
            @checkAll="checkAll"
        >
        </LineTeamsIndex>
     
   
</template>
```

child

```js
<script setup>
defineEmits(["update:selectedItems", "update:isCheckAll", "checkAll"]);

const props = defineProps({
    teams: Object,
    selectedItems: Object,
    isCheckAll: Boolean,
});

</script>
```

```html
<template>
        <template v-slot:body>
            <tr v-for="team in $page.props.teams.data" :key="team.id">
                <td>
                    <div class="form-check font-size-16">
                        <input
                            :id="team.id"
                            :value="team.id"
                            :checked="selectedItems.includes(team.id)"
                            @change="
                                $emit(
                                    'update:selectedItems',
                                    $event.target.value
                                )
                            "
                            class="form-check-input"
                            type="checkbox"
                        />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>{{ team.id }}</td>
                <td>
                    {{ team.name }}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </template>
 </template>
```

Here is a part of the code related to the SelectedItems array. Two-way binding via the built-in v-model is required. But it either doesn't work, or I get a data mismatch error " [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "SelectedItems". Expected Object, got String with value "88"". Tell me how to correctly transfer (use) the built-in v-model vue 3 to add data to the array and delete using concise code? Despite the fact that in the child component I have 2 models (not one) that are bound in the parent component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you emit `$event.target.value` it's the string value of the checkbox (equal to team.id), but the v-model is an array and you can't assign a string to an array. You need to instead emit an array with **all** the checkbox values that the v-model should contain.

Instead of emitting from the template, call a method on `@change`:

```html
<input
:id="team.id"
:value="team.id"
:checked="selectedItems.includes(team.id)"
@change="updateSelection($event.target.value)"
class="form-check-input"
type="checkbox"
/>
```

In the method, make a shallow copy of the prop array.  Push or splice the updated checkbox value to/from the array.  Emit that array with your `@update:selectedItems` event. I also include one way you might update the `isCheckAll` v-model

```js
const updateSelection = checkboxVal => {
  const selectedItemsCopy = [...props.selectedItems];
  const index = selectedItemsCopy.indexOf(checkboxVal);
  if (index !== -1) {
    selectedItemsCopy.splice(index, 1);
  } else {
    selectedItemsCopy.push(checkboxVal);
  }
  emit('update:selectedItems', selectedItemsCopy);
  
  if (selectedItemsCopy.length === props.teams.data.length) {
    emit('update:isCheckAll', true);
  } else {
    emit('update:isCheckAll', false);
  }
};
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks. But is it possible to do this in simple ways, without writing your own functions? The fact that you can write your own function and bind it to an event. The help shows a simple way without writing a separate code for handler functions, only the v-model binding is used and an array is assigned. vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#checkbox That's my goal.

Comment: as far as I know, you can't simplify much more than this when the [v-model is attached to a custom component](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#usage-with-v-model). You must bind the input value, and you must use an emit.  v-model's with primitive values are definitely simpler to handle, but objects and arrays require more custom work

Comment: You're welcome! If your problem is resolved please consider marking the answer as correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's a prop data type issue. You're saying that `selectedItems` should be a Javascript `Object` when passing it as a prop, but you're passing `String` instead.

Either change the expected data type:

```
defineEmits(["update:selectedItems", "update:isCheckAll", "checkAll"]);

const props = defineProps({
    teams: Object,
    selectedItems: String, // This is changed to 'String'
    isCheckAll: Boolean,
});
```

or pass the value through as an object instead:

```
v-model:selected-items="{slectedItems: models.teams.selected}"
```

Comment: No. Thats dont work